# RecycleView Unknown class

Tags: android, python, listview, kivy

I'm trying to create a sort of "ListView" for a mobile app using Kivy/Python.
Regarding to the main documentation of a [ListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#module-kivy.uix.listview), seems to be "deprecated".

> ListView has been deprecated, use RecycleView instead.

Well, I gave a look to [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#module-kivy.uix.recycleview), but unfortunately I get an error while using it in the KV module.

> kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class

I don't actually get what's wrong with it, i mean, is there something i should know about? The error is pretty straightforward, so my question is: Does kivy provide this module by default? or do i have to download it for some reason?

I've been asking in the #kivy channel on IRC for such a day, but nobody seem to know the answer, or at least they do not answer me.

Comment: RecyclerView is not provided by default on normal Android/Java/Gradle app, so I don't think it would be provided by default on kivy. On gradle you have to add the library to the project with the line `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'`. You probably just have to find the matching call for kivy.

Comment: do you use kivy 1.9.2 ?

Comment: Does it work on your PC, and breaks just on the android?

Comment: @jligeza I'm still in development on the PC, didn't try on android. But i won't do it right now since it doesn't work.

Comment: is this `kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class ` your complete error?. and would you show your code maybe. Should be `Unknown class YourClass` or something

Comment: Use [this example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/widgets/recycleview) as a reference, look what did you do wrong and correct it. Basically, if can't find what you put into RecycleView, most likely to `RecycleView.viewclass`. Maybe you've even put the class you want after the RecycleView code, therefore it could "overlook" it(I don't remember if the order of classes is important in kv, e.g. class before recycle). If you want it in python only, look how I handle it in [KrySA](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KrySA/blob/41937333f5bb0ffd03964aeaa296e755909d075c/krysa/main.py#L236).